# Layout of input elements is squashed in IE8

Tags: html, css, windows, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

Wondering if anyone can help with an IE8 issue, I've searched high and low and tried many different things. On a WordPress site for a client, an input text box appears much smaller than it should, and off to the side of the page, as compared with all other browsers I've tested.

You can see a grab of how the page looks on IE8 (on Windows 7) here:
http://perfectitaliano3.fonterra.safecom.com.au/wp-content/uploads/grab2.jpg

If you compare that to the page http://perfectitaliano3.fonterra.safecom.com.au/recipe/potato-rosemary-and-speck-pizza/ in a modern browser you’ll see the width and placement of the search box and filter dropdown menu at the top right is all messed up.

I'm a bit a noob at IE8 issues, but I’ve tried changing the css, patching it with modern.js, html5 shiv, modernizr, all sorts of things, but nothing makes any difference!

If you have any suggestions please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#top #s{
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 47px 0px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for answering @Jenti. I tried your suggestion but it didn't seem to work, although because it's now live I tried it in the developer tools in a virtual machine version of IE8, so one can never be sure ;)

However I've since found a solution, I added the following:

```
#searchform > div {
    width: 500px;
}
#s {
    display: table-cell !important;
}
```

and that seemed to do it.  Thanks again and appreciate it.